# How to add date in each rows based on conditions

Tags: r

I have data frame `before`

```
before <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a"),
             date = c("2011-12-18","2011-12-24"),
             apple_days = c(3, 2),
             banana_days = c(3, 2),
             mango_days = c(1, 5))
```

and I would like to change it like below, `after`. 
Rows would be added according to `apple_days`, `banana_days`, `mango_days` and I want to make `date` increase by 1.

```
after <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"),
             date = c("2011-12-18","2011-12-19","2011-12-20","2011-12-24",
                      "2011-12-25","2011-12-26","2011-12-27","2011-12-28"),
             apple_days = c(1,1,1,1,1,"","",""),
             banana_days = c(1,1,1,1,1,"","",""),
             mango_days = c(1,"","",1,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: Your `date` in `after` does not always increase by 1. What is the rule? And how do `c(3, 2)` and `c(1, 5)` become `c(1,1,1,1,1,"","","")` and `c(1,"","",1,1,1,1,1)` respectively?

Comment: there's col "apple_days", "banana_days", "mango_day", and date follows max value of those. If mango_days = 5, apple = 2, and banana=2, date have to be increase five times by 1. like "18/1/1, 18/1/2, 18/1/3, 18/1/4, 18/1/5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R attempt:

```
vars <- c("apple_days", "banana_days", "mango_days")
cnt <- do.call(pmax, before[vars])
cntseq <- sequence(cnt)
after <- before[rep(seq_len(nrow(before)), cnt), ]
after[vars] <- lapply(after[vars], function(x) as.numeric(x >= cntseq) )
after$date <- as.Date(after$date) + cntseq - 1
```

Set the variables of interest, find the maximum value in each row, repeat the rows. Check if the original values are less than a sequence along the new rows. Add the row sequence on to the original date.

```
#    id       date apple_days banana_days mango_days
#1    a 2011-12-18          1           1          1
#1.1  a 2011-12-19          1           1          0
#1.2  a 2011-12-20          1           1          0
#2    a 2011-12-24          1           1          1
#2.1  a 2011-12-25          1           1          1
#2.2  a 2011-12-26          0           0          1
#2.3  a 2011-12-27          0           0          1
#2.4  a 2011-12-28          0           0          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse`/`lubridate` option

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
before %>%
     mutate(ndays = do.call(pmax, .[, -(1:2)])) %>%
     rowwise() %>%
     mutate(tmp = list(ymd(date) + days(0:(ndays - 1)))) %>%
     unnest() %>%
     group_by(date) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(contains("_days")), function(x)
         replace(rep(0, length(x)), 1:unique(x), 1)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-ndays, -date) %>%
    rename(date = tmp)
## A tibble: 8 x 5
#  id    apple_days banana_days mango_days date
#  <fct>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl> <date>
#1 a             1.          1.         1. 2011-12-18
#2 a             1.          1.         0. 2011-12-19
#3 a             1.          1.         0. 2011-12-20
#4 a             1.          1.         1. 2011-12-24
#5 a             1.          1.         1. 2011-12-25
#6 a             0.          0.         1. 2011-12-26
#7 a             0.          0.         1. 2011-12-27
#8 a             0.          0.         1. 2011-12-28
```

This seems oddly lengthy, I'm curious to know about shorter `dplyr`/`tidyverse` options.

---

A slight variation using `rlang::!!!` syntax

```
before %>%
     rowwise() %>%
     mutate(
         ndays = max(!!!syms(grep("_days", names(.), value = T))),
         tmp = list(ymd(date) + days(0:(ndays - 1)))) %>%
     unnest() %>%
     group_by(date) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(contains("_days")), function(x)
         replace(rep(0, length(x)), 1:unique(x), 1)) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     select(-ndays, -date) %>%
     rename(date = tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
before %>%
  mutate(ndays = pmax(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[-(1:2)])), 
  date = map2(as.Date(date), ndays,  ~ seq(.x, .x + .y - 1, by = 'day')))  %>% 
  rowwise()  %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("_days")),
           funs(list(+!is.na(`length<-`(seq(.), ndays))))) %>% 
  unnest 
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  id    date       apple_days banana_days mango_days
#  <fct> <date>          <int>       <int>      <int>
#1 a     2011-12-18          1           1          1
#2 a     2011-12-19          1           1          0
#3 a     2011-12-20          1           1          0
#4 a     2011-12-24          1           1          1
#5 a     2011-12-25          1           1          1
#6 a     2011-12-26          0           0          1
#7 a     2011-12-27          0           0          1
#8 a     2011-12-28          0           0          1
```